# powershell 5.1 on windows server 2016 not working

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-v5.0

I'm following exercise 1 of this Microsoft [official Azure lab](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/9078c800f062a1dc1271c8ad3e0a0d43/asset-v1:Microsoft+AZURE207x+4T2017+type@asset+block/Databases_in_Azure_Practical_Exercises.pdf) under the heading `Deploying Azure SQL Database by using the Azure PowerShell`. The VM machine in the lab is `Windows Server 2016`. When I run the the following command of step 6 it prompts me for an input shown below. Not sure what input I need to put there. **Note**: I've installed Azure PowerShell 5.1 from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases):

**Step 6 of above linked tutorial**:

```
PS C:\Users\Student> $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Pa55w.rd1234' –AsPlainText –Force
$cred = New-Object
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Student',$pass)
server = New-AzureRmSqlServer –ServerName 'raztestsqlserver' -
SqlAdministratorCredentials $cred –Location 'centralus' -
ServerVersion '12.0' –ResourceGroupName 'SQLDBRG'
```

**PS prompt the following**:

```
cmdlet New-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
TypeName:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Azure Power Shell issue.

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Student',$pass)
```

There is a line break when you copy script.

[image]

The script should like below:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Pa55w.rd1234' –AsPlainText –Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Student',$pass)
$server = New-AzureRmSqlServer –ServerName 'raztestsqlserver' -SqlAdministratorCredentials $cred –Location 'centralus' -ServerVersion '12.0' –ResourceGroupName 'SQLDBRG'
```

Comment: @nam I update my answer. You need move link break in your script.

Comment: @nam I test in my lab, the script works for me.

Comment: @ShengbaoShuiMSFT You seem to have identified the mistake I'm making. I ran the first line (shown in your screeshot) and it prompted me for an input for `TypeName`.  **Question**: what do I type in the input there? I typed  user name `Student` but it gave me the error `cannot find the type Student`

Comment: @ShengbaoShuiMSFT Your suggestion worked. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I'm in a learning mode for Powershell.

Comment: @nam The `TypeName` is `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Student',$pass)`.

Comment: @nam I suggest you could copy script to NotePad++ not directly to Power Shell. You will find the line break.

Comment: @nam Using NotePad++, you will see the difference clearly. https://imgur.com/a/cdfs7

Comment: Would you have an answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/884729/425441) post.

Comment: OK, I will check. Sorry, I am not at office, I will answet you after a hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69147/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-nam).