# Configuring Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure

I'm working on exercise 4 of this [Azure Official Lab](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/9078c800f062a1dc1271c8ad3e0a0d43/asset-v1:Microsoft+AZURE207x+4T2017+type@asset+block/Databases_in_Azure_Practical_Exercises.pdf). But the instructions for creating an `Azure AD user` seem outdated there since in the new portal I cannot find the information they are asking for in their walk-through. For example, step 3 says `In the Azure Active Directory blade, click Domain names and note the name assigned by default to your Azure Active Directory (the name will have the .onmicrosoft.com suffix)`. But I don't see this info in the new portal.

**Question**: What would be the alternate steps in the new portal for the above tutorial so I can complete it in the new portal?

Comment: Are you sure that's not written for the ARM portal? My understanding is that the word "blade" is only used in instructions for the ARM portal.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I assume it's written for ARM portal. But the new ARM portal does not have some of the info provided in the tutorial.

Comment: @nam If you don't add your custom domain to Azure, yes, your default Azure AD name is .onmicrosoft.com suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/add-users-azure-active-directory).

1.Sign in to the Azure Active Directory admin center with an account that's a global admin for the directory.

2.Select Azure Active Directory and then Users and groups.

3.On Users and groups, select All users, and then select New user.

[image]

Note: The user name is @.onmicrosoft.com.

Then when you set admin, you will see the user.

[image]

Comment: You could add user on Azure Portal or Azure AD Portal, they are same. It is same with this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/884770/unable-to-login-to-azure-sql-server-using-azure-active-directory-account/884785#884785).

Comment: Hi, if it helps, you could accept it as an answer. It will help more people in the community. Thanks.