# Unable to login to Azure SQL Server using Azure Active Directory account

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-sql

Using Azure Trial Free account to practice on their lab tutorials. I'm not clear on steps 5 and 6 of Exercise 4 on this [Azure Official Lab](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/9078c800f062a1dc1271c8ad3e0a0d43/asset-v1:Microsoft+AZURE207x+4T2017+type@asset+block/Databases_in_Azure_Practical_Exercises.pdf). When I login using `ADSQLAdmin` it says (as expected) account does not exist.

```
4. From the Azure Active Directory blade, create a new Azure AD user with the following
settings:
• Name: ADSQLAdmin
• User name: ADSQLAdmin@<your_Azure_AD_domain_name>
• Profile: Not configured
• Properties: Default
• Groups: 0 groups selected
• Directory role: User
• Password: click Show Password to view the auto-generated password 
5. Start another Internet Explorer InPrivate Browsing session and navigate to the Azure
Portal at https://portal.azure.com.
6. Sign in with the ADSQLAdmin account and, when prompted, change its password to
Pa55w.rd1234
```

Comment: Did you join the server to the domain?

Comment: @ToddWilcox How do we do that?. The lab did not mention it. Also, so you know: I'm using Azure Free Account for trial.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui Which dll would that be? Maybe, you could point to a link.

Comment: @nam You could check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a user name `ADSQLAdmin` in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got it (thanks). So in step 6 (of my post) I needed to use user name as `ADSQLAdmin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com` where`xxxx` is the default directory name that in my case was my Microsoft loginname appended with hotmail. For example if I am logging in to Azure with my MS email as JohnDoe@hotmail.com then `xxxx` would be JohnDoehotmail. Then in step 6, I logged-in to Azure using `ADSQLAdmin@JohnDoehotmail.onmicrosoft.com` and it prompted me to change my password from old password (similar to the one shown in your screenshot) to a new password.